# Verwendung von "etwas für [...] befinden"

Tags: word-usage, relative-clause

Die Ausgangsaussage sieht so aus:

> Ich tue es, weil ich es für richtig befinde.

Wenn das zugehörige Adjektiv aber schon vorher erwähnt wird, wie etwa in

> Ich tue es, weil es richtig ist bzw. ich es ___ befinde.

was kann dann statt ___ stehen?

> - dafür
> - so
> - als solches
> - gar nichts (also der zweite Satz ist unmöglich)
> - ...

Zwei Varianten ohne "es":

> Ich tue es, weil es richtig ist bzw. ich befinde, dass es so ist.
>   Ich tue es, weil es richtig ist bzw. ich so befinde.

Welche von den obigen Varianten geht nun in Ordnung bzw. was für andere Möglichkeiten gibt es, "befinden" in diesem Sinne zu benutzen, ohne dass das zugehörige Adjektiv direkt davor steht?

Ein anderer Satz mit der gleichen Problematik: "Er befindet es dafür, wofür sie es befindet". (Ich weiß, das würde nie jemand so sagen, aber rein theoretisch halt.) Da wäre dann eben wieder die Frage, ob es denn nur "Er befindet (so) wie sie" oder sonstwie heißen kann.

Comment: Ausm Bauch heraus kann "als solches" nur in Verbindung mit einem Nomen verwendet werden. Ich kann da aber auch falsch liegen.

Comment: Ich denke nicht, daß irgendeiner der Vorschläge oder auch eine andere Formulierung funktioniert. Man würde einfach _für richtig_ in die Lücke einsetzen.

Comment: @chirlu Das liegt aber einzig am Verb "befinden", was sehr gehoben ist. Insgesamt wirkt der ganze Satz etwas schräg.

Comment: @Em1: D.h. dieser Satz wäre OK: _Bist du blöd oder willst du mich dafür verkaufen?_

Comment: @chirlu Nein, aber "Bin ich blöd oder willst du mich nur dafür verkaufen" wäre es. Wäre, weil trotzdem sehr unschön. Aber nicht falsch. Nur wieso kommst du mit nem ganz anderen Beispiel auf. Im Kontext der Frage geht es um "etwas für etwas befinden", also sollten wir dabei bleiben. Ich finde "so" übrigens in dem Beispiel richtig, "dafür" grammatisch auch, aber wohl nicht das, was ich sagen würde.

Comment: @Em1: Du hattest gesagt, es liege am Register (gehoben), daher wollte ich etwas Umgangssprachliches. Ich kann auch den Satz nicht für gut befinden.

Comment: @chirlu Fair enough. Ich meinte nur, wenn man in genau dem Satz das Wort so austauscht, dass es etwas "normaler" klingt, dann empfinde ich den Satz halt weniger holprig und hätte kein Problem damit, "dafür" oder "so" dort einzusetzen.

Answer (score 2):

Die pronominale Substitution für eine Konstruktion mit "für" ist "dafür", punktum. Es spielt keine Rolle, ob das "für" direkte oder übertragene Bedeutung hat, oder ob die Konstruktion üblich oder unüblich ist.

Die vorgeschlagene Ersetzung ist in der Tat ungebräuchlich, aber das liegt daran, daß die Konstruktion an sich ungebräuchlich ist, nicht daran, daß sie irgendwelchen Sonderregeln unterliegen würde.

Comment: Danke! Was sagst du zu den letzten zwei Varianten ohne "es"?